# SCSS nesting not working

Tags: css, sass

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <p class="red">Text 1</p>
  <p class="red">Text 2</p>
  <p class="red">Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
  <p class="stars">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</p>
  <p class="NEXT"><span>NEXT</span></p>
  <p class="link1">Text 5</p>
  <p class="link2">www.hello.com</p>
  <p class="link3">HELLO!</p>
</div>
```

With the CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 250px;
    background: #e9e3d9;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #ad9e8b;
  font-size: 20px;

  .red {
    color: #ae463d;
  }

  .stars {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: #ae463d;
  }

  .link1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #ae463d;
  }

  .link2 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .link3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
 }

.NEXT {
  text-align: center;
  color: #474340;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #474340; 
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  background: #e9e3d9; 
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

Also a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r7s5stq6/

But as you might be able to see, the CSS doesn't work for the nested classes. If I remove the nesting and just put `.red` alone etc., it works. But I have now been sitting for two hours trying to figure out why this doesn't work when nesting... In my head it seems like this is the way I have done it throughout my entire website now, but my last page I'm making, this just happens, and I can't see if I'm doing something wrong or what the hell is wrong here. I've tried using + and `p.red`, but that doesn't help either. Maybe it's because it's getting too late, but I really can't figure this out :D

What am I doing wrong here ?

And yes, I like the nesting quite a bit, since I don't have to worry about the common class names being used other places.

Comment: Have you used preprocessors?

Comment: The only nested css you will get is .main .red, .main .stars, .main .link1...

Comment: Ah, sorry... I am using SCSS, so the nesting should work.

Comment: If you'd use SCSS, it'd work: [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Justastudent/r7s5stq6/4/) where I enabled SCSS. Can you [edit] your question and include *how* you use SCSS? It sounds like something is going wrong there.

Comment: Please edit your question and mention that you use `SCSS`. And maybe also tag [SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass)

Comment: I literally have no idea why this suddenly works... I have spent hours compiling it, and then after I just got it back from the Fiddle, it works... So sorry for wasting your time guys...

Comment: I am voting to close this question as apparently, the **problem can no longer be reproduced**.

Answer (score 1):

Hi kindly check if you are already watching/writing your scss script with the command :

sass --watch stylename.scss:stylename.css

make sure you run this on a command line box.

Also make sure that the element you are calling in your css is iniside nest element.

like

```
<div class="sample><p id="red"></p></div>
```

and you nest like this:

```
.sample{background#000; #red{color:red;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure css, if you want nesting similar to this

```
.class1, .class2 {
  # some stuff
}
.class2 {
  # some more stuff
}
```

Or you might need to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)

Answer (score -2):

This is the Working CSS Code

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 250px;
    background: #e9e3d9;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
    color: #ad9e8b;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.red {
    color: red !important;
}

.stars {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: #ae463d;
}

.link1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #ae463d;
}

.link2 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.link3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}




.NEXT {
    text-align: center;
    color: #474340;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #474340; 
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}

span {
    background: #e9e3d9; 
    padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

You had a problem with the Closing bracket.

Comment: OP said he wanted to use nesting so there was no missing bracket. It was intentionally left out.

Answer (score -2):

just add "}" after main are you making fun by posting this